# Just trying to delete lines of several .txt files - but keep getting SED error

Tags: sed, terminal, glob

So, I am trying to delete the first 23 lines of many .txt files. This is what I am currently doing:

`sed -i -e 1,23d * .txt`

but it gives me a weird error:

`sed: 1: "1,23": command expected`

I have no idea what to do.              _

Comment: Please do not change the content of your question if an answer has already been given.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
sed -i -e '1,23d' *.txt
#              ^    mandatory 'd'
#                 ^
#       no space between * and .txt
```

Comment: Thank you! However, now it says this:
`sed: 1: "1,23": command expected`

Comment: Are you sure you have the trailing `d` in the `sed` command?

Comment: What is that? I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @MiaFrothingham `'1,23d'` <- the `d` there

Comment: You are right! I did not have it! so I added it this time and it says `sed: *.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: @MiaFrothingham That simply means that there are no files with the extension `.txt` in the current directory.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MiaFrothingham Why doesn't it make sense? That's what it means. Was does it print if you do `echo *.txt`  or `ls *.txt`?

Comment: `*.txt` - it says this!

Comment: @MiaFrothingham Have you set `set -o noglob` to turn off wildcard matching (globbing)?  What does it print if you do `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt'` ? If the `find` command doesn't print anything, there are no `.txt` files in the directory.

Comment: `shopt -po noglob` will show; or `echo $-` having `f`.

Answer (score 0):

The original question (before editing) showed:

```
sed -i -e 1,23d * .txt
```

but it gives me a weird error:

```
sed: Applications: in-place editing only works for regular files
```

The space between `*` and `.txt` was a mistake, but is an explanation of the weird error: It looks for all files as well as for the hidden file `.txt`.
Linux considers the directory `Application` as a file, but `sed` does not work on files.
The directory Application suggests that the files might come from Windows.
Another question is why `echo *.txt` don't show the txt files Mia was expecting. A logical explanation is that the files originated from Windows and Mia doesn't know that Linux is case sensitive. Files like `A.TXT` and `b.Txt` don't match `*.txt`.

When all txt files end with TXT, you can do

```
sed -i -e '1,23d' *.TXT
```

When you have a mix of upper- and lower case, the easiest way is

```
sed -i -e '1,23d' *.[tT][xX][tT]
```